# Pan gesture breaks UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using `UIPanGesture` to move my tableview frame up in the container frame until a certain y offset. Its working nicely. The problem is that after reached that y offset, I want to be able to scroll my tableview which was disabled by **panGestureRecognizer**.
How do I gain the scrolling capability of `UITableView` back?

I have tried setting `tableview.scrollEnabled` to `true` after the pan has ended. That doesn't seem to work.

Edit: The code that I am using to pan is as follows:

```
func panned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let originalState = tableView.frame
    let upperLimit = CGFloat(50)
    let loweLimit = CGFloat(200)
    switch (gesture.state) {
    case .began:
        print("Began")
        break;
    case .changed:

        let movement = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        var frame = self.tableView.frame;
        frame.origin.y += movement.y;

        if(frame.origin.y >= upperLimit && frame.origin.y <= 500){
            frame.size.height -= movement.y;
            self.tableView.frame = frame;
            gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), in: self.view)
        }

        break;
    case .ended:
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        print("end")
        break
    case .cancelled:
        //NSLog(@"End");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of your requirement as no code has been shown, but try this way by setting true in the "shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer"  method. I guess you can achieve the functionality.
Let me know the result.

Comment: Ok so i implemented the method you suggested and its working but now the `UITableView` is scrolling while it is being panned. Is there a way to  disable scrolling while the tableView is being panned?

Comment: @Eric Aya, Thank you for the information. But I just tried to make the question as more human readable. So I check for the grammar, tags, etc. Is that wrong ? Should not i do that?

Comment: I did not added "Any help would be appreciated" kind of stuff, I guess i did not removed it and posted, so it came as it is. Any way thanks for the information. I will be cautious next time.

Comment: @Janmenjaya I tried your solution and posted the result in one of the comments above. Can you please suggest something? Also guys, I am sort of new here and dont know much about the best practices to follow. Please excuse the noobiotic behaviour:P

Comment: Do you need this new gesture after you reach your destination? You could remove it if you don't.

Comment: @ohr thanks for the suggestion. I did that and its all sorted now.